# How to compile Xtend sources, with the Standalone Compiler?

Tags: java, jar, xtend

This is my first question.

I created the standalone compiler of **Xtend** with instructions below.

- Built with **Ant** and **Ivy**
- Directories are: **lib/**, **build/**
- **"xtend-compiler.jar"** will be output on **build/**
- Libraries are downloaded on **lib/**
- the Jar-file contains dependent libraries
- Main-class is **org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.Main**

**build.xml:**

```
<project name="xtend-compiler" default="jar-run" basedir="." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
  <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
  <property name="build.dir" value="build" />

  <path id="lib.path.id">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}"/>
  </path>

  <!-- resolve -->
  <target name="resolve">
    <mkdir dir="${lib.dir}"/>
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact].[ext]"/>
  </target>

  <!-- jar -->
  <target name="jar">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <copy file="${lib.dir}/org.eclipse.xtend.standalone.jar" tofile="${build.dir}/xtend-compiler.jar"/>
    <jar update="true" destfile="${build.dir}/xtend-compiler.jar">
      <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" excludes="org.eclipse.xtend.standalone.jar"/>
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.Main"/>
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <!-- run -->
  <target name="run">
    <java jar="${build.dir}/xtend-compiler.jar" fork="true">
    </java>
  </target>

  <target name="jar-run" depends="jar,run">
  </target>
</project>
```

**ivy.xml:**

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="" module="xtend-compiler"/>

    <configurations>
      <conf name="web"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency org="org.eclipse.xtend" name="org.eclipse.xtend.standalone" rev="2.4.3" conf="web->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

---

After I built Jar-file, I tried to run

```
java -jar build/xtend-compiler.jar
```

this shows:

```
Usage: Main <options> <source directories>
where possible options include:
-d <directory>             Specify where to place generated xtend files
-tp <path>                 Temp directory to hold generated stubs and classes
-cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files
-encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
-useCurrentClassLoader     Use current classloader as parent classloader
```

Then I want to compile **HelloWorld.xtend**:

```
class HelloWorld {
  def static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World")
  }
}
```

but I couldn't do that. For example:

```
java -jar build/xtend-compiler.jar HelloWorld.xtend

  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
  at org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.XtendBatchCompiler.configureWorkspace(XtendBatchCompiler.java:258)
  at org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.XtendBatchCompiler.compile(XtendBatchCompiler.java:273)
  at org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.Main.main(Main.java:48)
```

The source files are in **resource** directory.

How to compile it?

#### Supplement

I found a source of **org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.Main**:

https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.xtend.core/src/org/eclipse/xtend/core/compiler/batch/Main.java

I'm reading it, but now I don't understand what to add for arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by myself.

```
java -jar build/xtend-compiler.jar -cp build/xtend-compiler.jar resource -d .

#  0  [main] INFO  e.compiler.batch.XtendBatchCompiler  - Compiling 1 source file to .
#  0  [main] INFO org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.XtendBatchCompiler  - Compiling 1 source file to .

javac -cp build/xtend-compiler.jar:. HelloWorld.java
java -cp build/xtend-compiler.jar:. HelloWorld

#  Hello World
```